# Problems with supporting tablets and handsets simultaneously - resources

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout

I just got a Samsung 10.1 tablet and apart from the fact that the screen layout is different and I clearly need to start specifying layout-large etc. I noticed a few other differences.

Can anyone help me with any of these issues (they're quite varied)?

1. In one of my layout files I reference an icon called facebook_icon which I have stored in my own project's drawable-hdpi folder. This is actually different to the standard facebook icon in the Facebook SDK but even though I'm just using @drawable/facebook_icon and haven't referenced the facebook SDK library from the layout file the image that is displayed on the tablet is the SDK icon and not the one from my own project! Why?

Comment: Can we get a moderator to come and break this question up into multiple questions? It's far too large for just a single question.

Comment: @Barry please ask this in separate questions. This will fit the Q&A style of stackoverflow better.

Comment: First question:  Tablets are generally mdpi screens, so that is likely why you're not finding the graphic.  For the others, I'll wait until they are broken up.

Comment: @Janusz. Sorry about that. Breaking it down now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That tablet is MDPI, so the SDK icon is an exact match (because it's in drawable/facebook_icon and your icon is in drawable-hdpi/facebook_icon, and the drawable directory without a qualifier is MDPI.)

Comment: Okay. That makes sense **but** drawable-mdpi/facebook_icon isn't in my project but in the Facebook-SDK. I thought I had to include the Facebook SDK in a namespace and use the icons that way if I wanted to do that?

Comment: I know that r14 of the Android tools compiled everything into the same namespace. 

I don't know if the current release separates namespaces or not.